# Destroy and unset session on certain pages only

Tags: php, session

Newbie question here but is it possible to unset `session` which was set. What I mean is I have file `connection.php` which make connection to database and it is included on each page/file.

There is one page `search.php` which I want to be accessible without user to be forced to log in. So what I have in the file is

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

      // some code which perform search here

?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
       search form here
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page is getting me to sign in page because I'm not logged. What I've tried is to put session destroy right after include of connection

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
session_destroy();
      // some code which perform search here

?>
```

This doesn't help and still redirecting me to sign in page. Is there any chance I can work around this?

Update: I this is where I check and save the session

```
<?php
$request = $_REQUEST;
if(!empty($request)) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = false;
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['password']) ) {

        $password = md5($_REQUEST['password']);

        $sql = "select users query";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            if ($row['type'] == 'admin' || $row['type'] == $_REQUEST['type'] ) {
                $_SESSION['user']=[
                    'id' => $row['id'],
                    'fname' => $row['fname'],
                    'email' => $row['email'],
                ];
                $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                if($_SESSION['user']['type'] == 'admin'){
                    header('Location: Approval.php');die;
                }
            }else {
                    header('Location: signup.php');die;
            }
        } else { $error = "Wrong Email and/or Password or Account not acitvated. Please try again."; }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you do not want to “unset” anything in the session or the complete session for this. You must have some code somewhere that checks via the session, whether the user is logged in or not, and if not redirects to your login page. At this point you want to check if the requested page was your search page - and in that case, simply not redirect to the login page.

Comment: you can use  the `__FILE__` constant to check the filename, and create a condition.

Comment: Thansk for the comments. I've added the file which I think is responsible for this. Can you help me a bit. Do I need to put this `$_SESSION['login'] = false;` in condition ?

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seems to work `if($_SESSION['login'] = false){if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == '../results.php'){header('Location: ../results.php');die;}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your connection.php file you can have an array with file names you want to exclude like (add it before or after the line $request = $_REQUEST;):

```
$file_excludes = array("search.php", "anotherfile.php");
```

Then get the current file being run and split the path (add it before the line if(!empty($request)) {):

```
$current_file = explode("/", __FILE__);
```

Then modify the line:

```
if(!empty($request)) {
```

To:

```
if(!empty($request) && !in_array($current_file[count($current_file) - 1], $file_excludes)) {
```

Okay here is another proposed solution now that I have more info:

```php
<?php
$current_file = explode("/", __FILE__);
include 'connection.php';

      // some code which perform search here

?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
       search form here
</body>
</html>
```

And leave the modified IF statement where it is. So you just initialize the `$current_file` within the search.php file. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks but this is not my connection.php file above. But I guess it still apply.?

Comment: I've added above lines in login file before `if(!empty($request)) {` but still redirects me to signup

Comment: did you change the `if(!empty($request)) {` to `if(!empty($request) && !in_array($current_file[count($current_file) - 1], $file_excludes)) {` ?

Comment: Yes, everything as you wrote.

Comment: I do apologize. There was an error in my code. `$file_excludes = ("search.php", "anotherfile.php");` is meant to be `$file_excludes = array("search.php", "anotherfile.php");`. I've updated my answer

Comment: Unfortunately still same. When I have include connection.php which has session start in results.php and perform search is redirecting me on login page

Comment: I see in your comments above you have `if($_SESSION['login'] = false)` - that will assign false to `$_SESSION['login']` not evaluate it. It should be `if($_SESSION['login'] === false)`

Comment: Changed it to `===` and still redirects to login. Is it matter that `if($_SESSION['login'] === false)` is inside the `if(!empty($request) && !in_array($current_file[count($current_file) - 1], $file_excludes)) {` or this doesn't matter?

Comment: is this the only place you are using `header('Location: signup.php');die;`? Within the code you provided in your question?

Comment: Yes, this is the only place.

Comment: please see my amended answer above. Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks. Will try in few mins and will let you know

Comment: Yes, now is working just great, Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Oops, false. It still redirects me..\